# How can i resolve this problem: Android Studio - Flutter - Dart - firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

How can i resolve this problem: Android Studio - Flutter - Dart - firebase

```
>     W/Firestore(28989): (21.3.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error:
> Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=The project chatone-46fb9 does not
> exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud
> Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to
> create a project or
> https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=chatone-46fb9
> to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud
> Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app
> and this app must not be disabled., cause=null}
>     W/Firestore(28989): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will
> operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to
> the backend.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the above error message, your app does not have a proper Internet connection. Please check permission in Android and IOS projects. Also, check whether you have put the correct JSON file.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking